# Gson cannot read its own date format

Tags: gson

I have a Java object that has a java.util.Date field.  When I do a System.out.println() on the Date object, it prints "2012-11-03".  Then when I do a gson.toJson() on the Java object, I can see that the Json representation of the Date field is "Nov 3, 2012".  Then when I try to create another instance of the Java object from the Json string using gson.fromJson(), I get the following exception:

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: Nov 3, 2012
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.DateTypeAdapter.deserializeToDate(DateTypeAdapter.java:81)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.DateTypeAdapter.read(DateTypeAdapter.java:66)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.DateTypeAdapter.read(DateTypeAdapter.java:41)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:93)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:172)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:795)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:761)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:710)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:682)
```

Why can't Gson handle its own date format?

Comment: this is so curious. I have the same error on a published app. The point is that code is the same for everyone (no flavours or country qualifiers) and 90% works, BUT in some country/device it fails like this,.deserializeToDate(DateTypeAdapter.java:81). What's your device and Locale?

Answer (score 4):

You have to use setDateFormat when creating gson with gsonbuilder.

like:

Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ").create();